# Is it possible to send mail using JMS

Tags: spring-data-jpa, jms

I created one Spring data JPA Application. In that I am handling exception using `@ControllerAdvice` and also generated custom error message(status Code, path, message,Time). I am saving that error message in database table. When I am saving that message in table at that time I want to send that message on mail also.
My Question is can I send mail using `JMS`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMS is an API, not a protocol. Therefore, there could theoretically be a JMS client implementation which uses the SMTP protocol to send messages, but I think this would be unlikely since many of the JMS API concepts would not map to the SMTP/email use-case.

Comment: when I am searching I found this link https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-jms/   can we use activeMQ ?

Comment: ActiveMQ is a message broker which supports JMS. It provides a JMS client implementation which uses the OpenWire protocol (a protocol created for ActiveMQ). ActiveMQ itself has no support for SMTP or email APIs. The link you provided even states, "Pay note, we aren’t sending an email message." That said, you could use ActiveMQ together with Apache Camel to send email using [Camel's mail component](http://camel.apache.org/mail.html).

Comment: ActiveMQ with Apache camel is one option. can we use java mail API?

Comment: Of course you can use the Java Mail API to send email; that's what it was created for. However, you were asking about using JMS to send email. You can send email via the Java Mail API, but not JMS messages.

Comment: which is good option java mail or ActiveMQ with Camel? or any other option is available

Comment: Which option is better for you will depend on your specific requirements. In general, if you use Java Mail then you can send email directly from your application. If you use ActiveMQ+Camel then you'll have to install and configure them and then a JMS message from your application. As far as what other options are available, you're probably better off asking a new question about that. We've already diverged quite a bit off your original question here. I believe my answer addressed your original question so please mark it accordingly.